# Java code with potential type mismatch works without error - why?

Tags: java, java-stream, functional-interface

I have come across this piece of java code, it seems to have type mismatch in line
`forEach(i -> s.submit(() -> waitTillFinished(cb)))`

here is the full code

```
public class Boat {
    private void waitTillFinished(CyclicBarrier c) {
        try {
            c.await();
            System.out.print("W");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void row(ExecutorService s) {
        var cb = new CyclicBarrier(5);
        IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(12).forEach(i -> s.submit(() -> waitTillFinished(cb)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] oars) {
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            new Boat().row(service);
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the return type of the lambda is Future<?> and the forEach() accepts Consumer(which return type is void). I'm trying to understand why this code is working fine even though there is type mismatch.

I have tried with this kind of scenario with user defined Functional Interface inplace of consumer, then the code failed to compile

Comment: If you don't use the return value of a method, it becomes `void` and can be used as such. `Object getName() { return "neela"; } Stream.of(1,2,3).forEach(i -> getName());` would work too (and is a lot simpler than your example). Useless, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks @knittl for clarification. After your hint, i decompiled the code. i thought, without braces, lambdas will return the value from `getGame()`. but in this case, the actual decompiled code looks like this `forEach((i) -> { this.getName(); });`. Here nothing is returning, the result of `getName()` is being ignored

Comment: Your lambda is an expression statement, and in that case the compiler will happily discard the result to make it compatible with void as expected by `Consumer`.

Comment: Functional interfaces usually have one method that needs to be implemented via a lambda. The consumer has this form `v,oid accept(int value);` No matter how we go about it in the code, a consumer always returns void. `getName` does gets called but a `forEach` never returns a result because of it. It would be better if you present the working and the non-working example. This is also because I'm not sure if the other question pointed out by closing this one is the same as yours.